# Scrapy different number of url return

Tags: python, scrapy

I've built a crawler to that craws within a fixed domain and extracts url matching a fix regex. If a particular url is seen, the crawler follows the link. The crawler works perfectly to extract url but everytime i run the crawler, it returns me different number of links i.e. the number of links differ everytime i run it. I'm using Scrapy to crawl. Is this some issue with scrapy ? The code is:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
   name = "xyz"
   allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
   start_urls = ["http://www.xyz.nl/Vacancies"] 
   rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\/V-\d{7}\/[\w\S]+']), callback='parse_item'),Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\?page\=\d+\&sortCriteria\=1']), follow=True),)



 def parse_item(self, response):

  outputfile = open('urllist.txt','a')
  print response.url
  outputfile.write(response.url+'\n')
```

Comment: As usual: Code please?

Comment: @sshashank124 there you go !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually writing the links and opening the file with `a` mode inside the `parse_item()` method, use scrapy's built-in [item exporters](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html). Define an item with a field for a link:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class MyItem(Item):
    url = Field()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "xyz"
    allowed_domains = ["xyz.nl"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.xyz.nl/Vacancies"]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\/V-\d{7}\/[\w\S]+']), callback='parse_item'),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\?page\=\d+\&sortCriteria\=1']), follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item
```